# Android PorterDuff.Mode error: PorterDuff cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, android

I've got a class which extends LinearLayout, can't figure out how to get PorterDuff.Mode working with this piece of code:

```
this.getBackground().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#a7d2e3"), PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
```

"PorterDuff cannot be resolved to a variable"

I've imported porterduff and from what I can see PorterDuff is a static class. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you import it correctly? Did you make a typo? `import android.graphics.PorterDuff;`

Comment: ah spot on, I was importing import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode! Thank you!!! I've spent ages pulling my hair out on this

Comment: Now I get NullPointerExceptions on that line. Strange because this.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED); works fine. The view is a sub class of LinearLayout...just wondering if you can't call getBackground/setColorFilter on a LinearLayout?

Comment: i have aplied this on ImageView but i m getting no result of color on imageview

Answer (score 28):

Add this to your imports, because for some reason, Eclipse doesn't automatically do it for this one:

`import android.graphics.PorterDuff;`

Answer (score 1):

Use only `Mode.DARKEN`, and then import `android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;`